# Natbib, sort&compress

Tags: citing, natbib

I have finally managed to get my references in my thesis how i want them, correct style etc. however for some reason the natbib package is managing to sort my references, but not compress them.

This means if i have referenced 4 references they appear as superscript 1,2,3,4 instead of 1-4. I have a feeling it might be a package conflict, but i am not sure. I am using the following packages,

```
\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\citestyle{nature}
```

Any help?

Comment: I forgot to say this throws up:

Latex Error: Option clash for package natbib.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please supply a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  As it stands the code you post, apart from the unknown watermark style file, works fine in a standard document.

Comment: I downloaded a template for this and as such i would not know how to make such a minimum working example (in the respect i do not know what to remove and what to keep). I tried %ing out all of the packages except natbib and putting them back in one by one to see if they were causing the clash, and it seems not.

Comment: I found the problem. My documentclass was calling up a style file that already had the natbib, plus extra options, loaded, thus when i tried to separately load the natbib in the .tex file it caused a clashed. Fixed now!

Comment: Please look at the link for MWE I gave - it provides information on how to construct one.  The code you post for example does not include information about which bibliography style you are using or examples of how you are citing articles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about due to a problem in style file not provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you want to have citations in sorted&compressed numeric-superscript mode, you could load the `cite` package with the `superscripts` option:

```
\usepackage[superscripts]{cite}
```

The options `sort` and `compress` are "true" by default with the `cite` package.

Of course, if you load the `cite` package, do not load `natbib` as well.